# I tried send photo to firebase with using python but i have got error

Tags: python, firebase

i am getting this error:

> AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'auth'

```
firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
storage=firebase.storage()
path_on_cloud="images/c1.png"
path_local="c1.png"
storage.child(path_on_cloud).put(path_local)
```

Comment: show the part of code you declare the connection as well as `request`

Comment: Since that code does not contain any references to `requests` or `auth`, this cannot be the code that caused the failure.

Comment: another part of code there are only config and importing pyrebase

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.